# Hand gesture origin for "David Melech Yisrael" song

Tags: history, song-poetry, provenance

What is the origin of the gestures for the song whose text is "David melech yisrael, chai chai v'kayam"?  (An example would be https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cWItJ0TF2fw.)

Comment: Fwiw I've seen the same motions to other tunes and words.

Comment: I don't think there's any religious source for that. It's just a 'fun dance' added in to get the kids more involved in the song. If anything, the source would probably be Sesame Street.

Comment: @msh210 can you provide an example of the other tunes and words?

Comment: @msh210 An example (perhaps the origin) is from the show [Grease](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fY5pmzmiDO8). (Warning--not very tzanua dancing behind that link)